# Is it possible to use GZIP compression on classic ASP pages?

Tags: asp-classic, compression, gzip

We've got a classic ASP application that is putting out some very large reports, where the resulting HTML is several MBs. We've made a lot of progress in trimming this down by reducing extraneous HTML, but I'd like to know if there's any way to enable GZIP compression on these dynamic .asp pages. I'm sure compressing them would be an enormous benefit to the file size.

All of the GZIP compression information I've seen only talks about supporting files or .aspx pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, that's just a matter of turning on compression in IIS. See this [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/25d2170b-09c0-45fd-8da4-898cf9a7d568.mspx?mfr=true) page for example.

Comment: Ah, that's the first link I've seen that actually mentions .asp pages. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [HttpZip from Port 80 Softwar](http://www.port80software.com/products/httpzip/)e. It basically just enables compression in IIS but from a GUI instead of getting into the metabase. I used it in a web-farm for a big enterprise ASP application.

Comment: Hmmmm. Spend $349 per-server, or open the metabase in notepad... tough choice

Comment: I agree, it is not worth the price. But as it just changes the settings you can just download the trial, use it and then uninstall it.